# R Shiny: source command prints TRUE on app

Tags: r, shiny

I am building a shiny application that should have different options for different user categories. Therefore, I have different subfiles where the inputs are definied and the dependent on the role the respective file is loaded via the `source` command.

It works, however, the `source` command always prints a `TRUE` on my shiny app. I can't get rid of it no matter what option of the source command I am trying.

[Here a screenshot of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eUUin.png)

And a minimal example: **app.R**

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)

# Define UI for app that draws a histogram ----
ui <- fluidPage(
    titlePanel("Hello Shiny!"),
    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
            source("sub.R", echo = FALSE, print.eval = FALSE),
        ),
        mainPanel(
            plotOutput(outputId = "distPlot")
        )
    )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
    output$distPlot <- renderPlot({
        x    <- faithful$waiting
        ggplot(tibble(x), aes(x=x)) + geom_histogram( binwidth = input$bins)
    })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

And the sourced file **sub.R**:

```
sliderInput(inputId = "bins",
            label = "Number of bins:",
            min = 0.1,
            max = 5,
            value = 1)
```

Thanks for any help in advance

Comment: Maybe just replace ```source("sub.R", echo = FALSE, print.eval = FALSE)``` with what you have for **sub.R** (the call to ```sliderInput```)?

Comment: That would of course be possible. However, this is only my minimal example. My real code is much longer and I try to keep it lean. The solution by r2evans with source("sub.R")[1] did the trick.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the fix [here](https://r-bar.net/organize-r-shiny-list-source/#When_Source_Fails_in_the_UI): add a `[1]` at the end of the `source(.)` command:

```r
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)

# Define UI for app that draws a histogram ----
ui <- fluidPage(
    titlePanel("Hello Shiny!"),
    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
            source("~/stackoverflow/17150062/sub.R", echo = FALSE, print.eval = FALSE)[1]
        ),
        mainPanel(
            plotOutput(outputId = "distPlot")
        )
    )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
    output$distPlot <- renderPlot({
        x    <- faithful$waiting
        ggplot(tibble(x), aes(x=x)) + geom_histogram( binwidth = input$bins)
    })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

[image]

Comment: Well that was easy. This is the solution. Thank you very much.